# How do I get ligatures and guillemets with Libertine and PDFLaTeX?

Tags: font-encodings, ligatures, libertine

I want:

- my document to be rendered in the Libertine (or Libertinus) typeface with all the default ligatures enabled (including *Th* and *Qu*);
- use guillemets (»«) and other special characters directly in the text;
- those guillemets to be rendered properly (and not as some resized ≪);
- to compile my document with PDFLaTeX.

My best attempt at this is:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
»Thesaurus frisst Quastenflosser!«
\end{document}
```

This produces the desired result, except for using fake guillemets, instead of Libertine’s:

[image: Product of the above source]

What I want is:

[image: Goal]

**How can I achieve this?**
I tried combinations of different options (such as `T1`) for `fontenc` or disabling it and `babel` to no avail.

There are several similar questions, but the solutions all use macros for the guillemets or XeLaTeX, which I am well aware of but cannot or do not want to use.

Comment: Why are you using `OT1` and not `T1`? The latter will usually tell latex that the various font parts are available in the font and shouldn't need to be constructed

Comment: @daleif I think it's about the ligatures: `libertine` cheats a bit and sneaks the Th and Qu ligatures in the OT1 encoding. This is not possible with T1.

Comment: well you could define the quotes to switch encoding, but be aware that while you gain ligatures with OT1 you loose copy& paste (and search) for umlauts.

Comment: @campa then one your probably use a proper font instead.

Comment: @daleif I wasn't necessarily agreeing with the purpose but only explaining the reason behind the choice...

Comment: Typesetting a document in German with OT1 would be a nightmare with hyphenation, because each *umlaut* would inhibit hyphenation past it. It's not difficult to define `»` and `«` to yield the desired glyph, but this wouldn't solve the *main* problem. If you need the Th and Qu ligatures and no hyphenation problems, you need to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @daleif: I tried `T1`, but as already noted, that disables the ligatures. I just use it as an example here, because it produces the closest results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, `T1` encoding and Libertine ligatures do not work together when using `pdftex`. Using the `OT1` encoding will give you the nice ligatures but will suppress hyphenation and break kerning in any word containing an umlaut or a `ß`, and will prevent any possibility of copy/pasting or searching for text in the final PDF document. Note also that not all automatic ligatures are meaningful, and you might need to break some of them manually: for example, `OT1` Libertine has a "*fb*" ligature which in most cases is not desired.

This being said, it is relatively easy to achieve what you want, and

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage[OT1]{fontenc} % is the default anyway
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not really necessary since 2018
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{»}{{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\guillemotright}}
\newunicodechar{«}{{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\guillemotleft}}

\begin{document}

»Thesaurus frisst Quastenflosser!«

\end{document}
```

will give the desired output

[image]

However, I must remark again that the drawbacks of using an `OT1` encoded font are enormous when writing in German. Since I don't think that the `Th` and `Qu` ligatures are soooo common in a normal text, I would rather use the `T1` encoding and define a macro for the desired ligature, e.g. something like

```
\newcommand*{\Qu}{{\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont Qu}}
```

Comment: Using `\usepackage{libertine}` without explicitly loading `fontenc` implies `OT1`, right?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft In this case yes, though this might not always be true: some font packages force `T1`.